# Winter Bash - неверные даты?

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, новогодние-шляпы

Получил шляпу "A New Hope". В описании указано:

> спросите, ответьте или проголосуйте 18-го декабря

Но получена она 17-го около 16 часов по Москве. Но отвечал я и утром, около 10 по Москве. Начало суток по UTC тоже далеко. Вот и не пойму - то ли у меня лыжи не едут, то ли время как-то странно считается... Баг?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы просто недооценили мощь тёмной стороны Силы!

Comment: @VladD Тёмной стороны мощь время менять способна! Не должен юный падаван мощь тёмной стороны недооценивать! :-)

Comment: Время — ничто по сравнению с Силой! Отдайся своей ярости, приди к нам на день раньше! (А ещё, у нас есть печеньки!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл [ответ на этот вопрос на Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159748/310448).

Если вкратце, то они начинают выдавать шляпы по UTC+-12, чтобы люди из крайних временных зон имели возможность получить шляпу в более удобное время. SE работает по UTC. Допустим, что мы в UTC и у нас полдень. А у кого-то это полночь.

Надеюсь, смог донести суть исходного текста.

И да: это не баг, это фича :)